# I have a problem with updating a database. Using method executeUpdate() tnrows error

Tags: java, sql, database

Part of code:

```
@Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JFrame adding = new JFrame();
    JTextField txtField = new JTextField(30);
    JTextField txtStr = new JTextField(30);
    JButton add = new JButton("Add");
    txtField.setToolTipText("Field name");
    txtStr.setToolTipText("Note");
    adding.setSize(400, 200);
    adding.setVisible(true);
    adding.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel pane = new JPanel();
    adding.getContentPane().add(pane);
    add.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

     @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             String strInsert = "INSERT INTO Pharmacy (" + txtField.getText() + ") VALUES (" + txtStr.getText() + ")";
             try {
                 state.executeUpdate(strInsert);
             } 
             catch (SQLException ex) {                    
            Logger.getLogger(NewDataBase.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
             }
          }

      });
      pane.add(add);
      pane.add(txtField);
      pane.add(txtStr);
  }
```

I have a problem with updating a database. Using method `executeUpdate()` tnrows error `user lacks privilege or object not found`:`'here goes entered data'`. But I do not try to find this object in database but try to add this object as a new note. So why do I have this error?

Comment: You are probably trying to access a table that does not exist.

Comment: It looks odd that the column name is a parameter and not fixed and also not that if the value to be inserted is a string it needs to be quoted with single quotes

Comment: what is the sql that is throwing this error? I.e. what's txtField.getText()

Comment: Add a `System.out.println(strInsert);` right before the `executeUpdate` to see  what query you are trying to execute. I suspect the column name is completely wrong